# Problems with a heat map and dendogram using heatmaply. R

Tags: r, heatmap

I’m interested in obtaining a heatmap with a dendogram using percentage of similarity between 10 groups as distance measurements.

The data structure is as follows:

```
af.w<-c(0,24.7,20.4,46.8,17.3,30,60.6,62.1,57.9,31.3)
af.g<-c(24.2,0,21.0,48.7,19.0,30.9,60.6,63.6,60.4,31.8)
af.e<-c(20.8,21.8,0,41.7,14.9,23.6,58.6,63.2,57.3,27.6)
af.h<-c(29.5,31.6,21.5,0,28.2,26.3,49.9,56.8,49.1,36.1)
af.s<-c(37.8,39.4,35.5,58.4,0,33.1,68.5,71.9,68.0, 47.7)
af.k<-c(61.8,61.8,56.8,69.3,51.3,0,75.6,78.9,74.8,64.0)
eu<-c(25.8,25.4,19.4,28.4,20.4,20,0,39.1,16.8,29.1)
asi<-c(18.5,21.3,18.5,29.0,20.0,18.6,28.8,0,24.0,22.0)
mi.ha<-c(27.4,31.6,23.9,32.7,25.8,23.1,23.9,40.5,0,30.9)
mi.aa<-c(20.6,19.7,15.1,44.1,18.7,23.6,56.3,58.6,54.2,0)
data<-cbind(af.w,af.g,af.e,af.h,af.s,af.k,eu,asi,mi.ha,mi.aa)
rownames(data)<-c("af.w","af.e","af.g","af.h","af.s","af.k","eu","asi","mi.ha","mi.aa")
data<-(100-data)
```

Percentages, of the pairwise comparisons, in both sides of the diagonal are not equal. This is because these percentages of similarity were obtained comparing groups with different sizes. The rationale is as follows: There is a certain number of elements in two given populations (N=250 in group A and N=500 in group B), they share 80 of these elements. In this case the proportion of similarity between A and B is 32% but between B and A is 16%.

Using package heatmaply and the following script I can get this figure:

```
heatmaply(data.2, margins = c(40, 130),
      seriate = "OLO")
```

[image]

As you can see there are two populations in the x axis that are interchanged (af.g and af.e). I believe this is because it’s more ease to build the upper dendogram with this configuration. However I want to get this figure with the correct alignment of the diagonal, ignoring if necessary, the upper dendogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibile solution:

```
heatmaply(data, margins = c(40, 130), Colv="Rowv", seriate = "OLO")
```

[image]